# Using a CAPTCHA within a jQuery UI Dialog confirmation box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, captcha, jquery-ui-dialog, confirm

I have a JQuery UI Dialog confirmation box that I need to make "extra sure" that the user *really* means it when they click "Confirm", so I think I want to use a CAPTCHA to capture this confirmation. Basically, disable the "Confirm" button in the popup until the entered text matches the CAPTCHA image.

Any ideas on how to do this, or even a better way to do this without resorting to a silly second "Are you really really really sure?" popup?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resolve a CAPTCHA only on the client side, they are very easily bypassed. Do not trust a browser.

So you really want to do the checking on the server. How to include it, depends on the captcha you choose to use.

If it is not a about a captcha, but making users think about "the right choice": What I did is giving users think time: Enabling the submit button only after a certain time. But displaying a "think timer" countdown. (btw: users hate it, but at least they think about their choice and not how to read a captcha).

Comment: You're right - it's not at all about CAPTCHA. It's about making the right choice, or at least capturing that the user went out of their way to make the wrong choice.

Comment: I think I'll just have them re-enter their password to confirm - simple, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think implementing a captcha will be extra work for you (and more annoyance for your users). Perhaps it's better to just throw:

```
return confirm('Submit the form now?');
```

Once they click confirm on the UI form.

Comment: A dialog that pops up another dialog is poor design, but I do appreciate the suggestion.